# using xarray.apply(np.nansum) with args

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have been trying to apply `np.nansum` to an xr.Dataset (xarray), but keep on coming up with errors. For a 3D dataset, I try to apply to axis=2. The syntax is not quite clear and I may have misunderstood the [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.apply.html?highlight=.apply), but I have tried:

```
ds.apply(np.nansum,axis=2)` and `ds.apply(lambda x: np.nansum(x,axis=2))
```

and get the same error:

> cannot set variable 'var' with 2-dimensional data without explicit
>   dimension names. Pass a tuple of (dims, data) instead.

I am guessing this means that it it does not know what dimension names to return to the new dataset object? Any ideas how to fix this?

And does anyone know why and when xarray might implement `np.nansum()`?
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't `xarray.Dataset.sum()` [already ignore](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.sum.html) NaNs? Can you just use that and pass `axis=2` (or `dim=dimname`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into here is that `nansum` returns a numpy `ndarray`, and not a `DataArray`, which is what the function passed into `apply` is supposed to return.

For `nansum`, you should just use `xarray.Dataset.sum`, which skips NaNs by default if your data is float.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy is correct that the built-in `sum()` method already skips NaN by default. But if you want to supply a custom aggregation function, you can do so with `reduce`, e.g., `ds.reduce(np.nansum, axis=2)`.

Comment: Thanks, `reduce` is a good one. Also handy to know (makes sense but not necessarily obvious)  that a custom function must return a dataArray

Comment: In the case that you use `ds.reduce`, you actually can use a function that returns a numpy array (as @shoyer has done here).